# Oracle: SELECT * FROM tablea a, tableb b WHERE a.fielda(+)=b.fieldb -- what is (+)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot understand what the role of the (+) is! (I "inherited" the statement through the automated update process of an application I am maintaining at the moment).

Is this some Oracle-specific operator? Does it have a special name that I can search for? 
It's kind of hard to google for a plus sign between brackets :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is an outer-join operator (old-school).

Comment: So it's the equivalent of SELECT * FROM tablea a OUTER JOIN tableb b ON a.fielda=b.fieldb ?

Comment: "WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2(+)" is the equivalent of "t1 left join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2"

Comment: @Cristina -- it is equivalent to `LEFT OUTER JOIN <table> ON (...)`.  http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm

Comment: And yes, as far as I know, it's Oracle-specific.

Comment: @Cristina.  No problem!  I agree with DCookie -- it is Oracle specific AFAIK.

Comment: @DCookie Thanks for the additional explanation!